# Although I have installed boto3 I am getting module not found error in Jupyter NOTEBOOK

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

```
!pip install boto3
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.34.48)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.35.0,>=1.34.48 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from boto3) (1.34.48)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from boto3) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.11.0,>=0.10.0 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from boto3) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.35.0,>=1.34.48->boto3) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.35.0,>=1.34.48->boto3) (1.26.18)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.35.0,>=1.34.48->boto3) (1.15.0)

import boto3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import boto3

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)

# >>> 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

In Jupyter Notebook It is using  Python Version 3.12 and in my environment variable also it is present.

How to resolve it?

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages` Pip is using python 3.8, not 3.12.

Comment: You are using conflicting python versions.  `pip` is using 3.8, but Jupyter is using 3.12.

Comment: Just a note on your line in the code block that says, "!pip install boto3". You should no longer be using exclamation points in conjunction with install commands for `pip` or `conda`. The magic pip install commands were added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. So in this example, you have run `%pip install boto3` in a cell. Then restarted the kernel. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands ...

Comment: <continued> that are current best practice. And they universally work now. Even in JupyterLite and Google Colab now. Take anything you come across suggesting an exclamation point in conjunction with an install command with a grain of salt as the advice may be outdated and not following current best practices. You'll have a better experience going forward if you adopt it now. And I think you wouldn't have had an issue if you had installed to the right environment. That last issue is what John Gordon is getting at. An exclamation point with an install command just runs it off in a temporary ...

Comment: <continued> shell instance which may or may not be the same environment in your system where the kernel backing your running Jupyter notebook is active. Given what you say, I'd guess that is what happened in your case, and would have been avoided if you had been following current best practice to use the magic install commands.  [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.